# Анимация кнопки на Андроид.

Tags: анимация, android-studio, android

Как сделать, чтобы когда нажимаешь на кнопку и держишь, то анимация оставалась, я сделал простенькую анимацию (по нажатию на кнопку размер кнопки уменьшается), но она срабатывает только после того, как отпустишь кнопку, а я хочу, чтобы нажал на кнопку и она уменьшилась и была такая пока не отпустишь, а когда отпускаешь, то возвращалась к нормальным размерам, как это сделать? Вот мой xml файл анимации:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shareInterpolator="false">

<scale
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0.7"
    android:toYScale="0.7" />

<scale
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой и топорный способ, следующий:

1. Пишите обработчик OnTouchListener для кнопки.
2. В обработчике ловите OnTouch и запускаете по нему анимацию.
3. Пишите AnimationListener и при завершении анимации ставите на кнопку что нужно.